# How to create backup schedule when someone created new repository with Collabnet Subversion Edge

Tags: svn, backup, collabnet

I'm using Collabnet Subversion Edge.
Is it possible to create a backup schedule of a repository automatically?
I searched hook script reference, but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid it's for a manual operation. I'm looking for how to do it by script. Thank you anyway.